# Word 2010 - Curly Quotes [Slovenian language]

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a pretty rudimentary question.

I would like to get curly quotes and not straight ones ("x" and 'x') in the document formatted in Slovenian language (Slavic language), which uses chevrons.

I have tried multiple options e.g. AutoFormat and AutoFormatAsYouType, but to no avail.

I can have curly quotes but I have to:

1. Change WORD interface into English (settings in AutoFormat change for smart quotes from »x« into "x", where I can check "x"; smart ones)
2. Format language in English and then apply replace "" for "".

Well this is not he most elegant solution, because during writing I still need Slovenian for proofing.

The past part is that in the past I somehow managed to do that, but I forgot how.

Comment: Curly quotes and not straight ones, then you show a double quote and a single quote... I have no idea what you mean. To see if I understand, what happens if you copy the content into notepad, and then recopy it back to Word. Does this do what you want?

Comment: Well I need curly quotes in Slavic languages that use chevrons. While it is possible to change the easly in ENG language in diffrent (e.g. French) there is not easier solution as posted above. I have succeded in making short cut on the keyboard, which till date, is the most elegant solution. But still LibreOffice has that option which quote to use and I was interested if Office has also?

Comment: You mean these? `„Test“`. It works for me in Word 2010 when I change the language to Slovak. But Word sometimes changed the language back to English as Autodetect language is turned on.